# Angular 4 pipe for checkbox not working properly

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

Hi I am new to the angular and I am trying to create an anuglar checkbox filter pipe to filter my products data!Here I have created a colors for checkboxes in my .ts file (I have not included the code which is not relevant to this issue)

```
public colors: any[] = [
{
  id: 1,
  color: "Black",
  selected: true,
},
{
  id: 2,
  color: "Green",
  selected: true,
}
]
```

I am using a pipe for the checkboxes -

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'selectBrand'
})
export class SelectBrandPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(check: any, checked?: any): any {
        console.log('checked', checked);
        return checked ? check.filter(sal => sal.type === checked) : check;
    }
}
```

In my HTML file -

```
<form>
    <div class="form-check brand-checkbox" *ngFor="let col of colors">
      <input class="form-check-input" 
             type="checkbox" 
             value="{{col.id}}" 
             id="{{col.id}}" 
             name="" 
             [(ngModel)]="col.selected">

      <label class="form-check-label" for="{{col.id}}">
        {{col.productColor}}
      </label>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="shop" *ngFor="let prod of productListShow">
    <div class="col-md-4" *ngFor="let product of prod.product | selectBrand: colors">
            <h5>{{product.productName}}</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting my products data from a service -

```
{
    id: 1,
    productName:'Products',
    product: [
        {
            productId: 1,
            productName: 'Shirt 1',
            productColor: 'Green',
        },
        {
            productId: 2,
            productName: 'Shirt 2',
            productColor: 'Black',
        },
    ],
},
```

When the code runs all the checkboxes are selected and I see no products and in my console log. I am getting -

```
checked 
(2) [{…}, {…}]
0
:
{id: 1, productColor: "Black", selected: true}
1
:
{id: 2, productColor: "Green", selected: true}
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array(0)
```

Comment: Can you put your code in stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/). It will be easier to spot the error

Comment: This isn't AngularJS 1.x, don't use Pipes for filtering/ordering. Just filter in your component or in a service. [No FilterPipe or OrderByPipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

Comment: Hi @AlexanderStaroselsky thanks, can you please guide on how to do it without pipes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are passing products Array as *check* and colors Array as *checked* into your pipeTransform function. Then you check if product.type (which btw does not exist according to your products model definition) is equal to colors Array. I guess this is not what you want to check.

Try with:

```ts
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'selectBrand',
    pure: false
})
export class SelectBrandPipe implements PipeTransform {
transform(products: any[], colors: any[]): any {

    const activeColors = colors.filter(c => c.selected).map(c => c.color)
    console.log('checked colors', activeColors.join(","));
    return products.filter(p => activeColors.includes(p.productColor));
    }
}
```

btw: if you really want to use a pipe for filtering, you need a impure pipe which is not recommended due to performance reasons.

i recommend to filter the products only when user changes the checkbox status by adding (ngModelChange) to the checkbox input-element, e.g:

```ts
<input class="form-check-input" 
             type="checkbox" 
             value="{{col.id}}" 
             id="{{col.id}}" 
             name="" 
             [(ngModel)]="col.selected"
             (ngModelChange)="filterProducts()">
```

In your component typescript add a function filterProducts which does the filtering:

```ts
  public filterProducts(): void {
    const filteredProductArray = new Array<any>();
    const activeColors = this.colors.filter(c => c.selected).map(c => c.color);
    this.productListShow.forEach(prod => {
        const filteredSubProducts = prod.product.filter(p => activeColors.includes(p.productColor));
         if(filteredSubProducts.length > 0){
             const clonedProduct = Object.assign({}, prod);
             clonedProduct.product = filteredSubProducts;
             filteredProductArray.push(clonedProduct);
         }
    });
    this.filteredProducts = filteredProductArray;
}
```

then use filteredProducts in ngFor instead of productListShow

Comment: Hi @A.Winnen I tried the method somehow Its not working. Can you please guide on how to do it without pipes

Comment: That pipe definitly works for me. Which issue do you experience ?

I edited my answer with a better approach of filtering the list only when a checkbox is changed.

Comment: hi! @A.Winnen, thanks for the answer, however I can't replace `productListShow ` with `filteredProducts `, as there are many other pipes integrated with it. Can you please suggest me a different way.

Comment: Hi! @A.Winnen, The `filterproducts` in  `this.filteredProducts = filteredProductArray;` is giving me an error `filteredProducts' does not exist on type 'ShopComponent'` Please help

Comment: Just define it... and use it In ngfor

Comment: Hi! @A.Winnen, I tried it and used it for ngFor, The checkbox works fine now, but it is showing all the categories when it loads, For jeans, it is showing Jeans, Shirts and Watches. Before it was loading correctly. Here is the stackblitz I have created - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-list    Please help

Comment: sure, you were iterating over the wrong array. I made some adjustments to your blitzstack: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-checkbox-list-3zqqrz

Comment: Hi! @A.Winner, Thanks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

NgModel for Checkbox:

```
<input id="colId{{i}}"  [checked]="col.active" class="" (change)=" col.active = !col.active" type="checkbox">
<label for="colId{{i}}" ></label>
```

Comment: Hi @Weslley, but it is giving me the same answer, may be something wrong.